# Kotlin navigation drawer activity route parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have started a Kotlin project using navigation drawer activity from Anroid studio template
https://github.com/TVart/NavDrawerActivity
As you can see there a 3 sub menu or routes (Home, Galaxy & Slideshow)
What I want is to route all these 3 routes to the same (unique) Fragment, and passing a custom parameter for each route, where I will load data from db according to this passed parameter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each time when you click, a variable could be added in the activity (or wherever you want), when the Fragment is called, could check previously this value in the activity from the fragment each time it loads.